# iOS12 adMob Rewarded video: test ad not working

Tags: xcode, admob, ios12

Until yesterday night AdMob test ad was working fine, but then it suddenly stopped working. 
I have tried all of the solutions proposed for similar problems but i'm still getting the same errors:

```
WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process
WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
filterBlacklist =     (
);
filterWhitelist =     (
);
noOverridingAllowed = 1;
restrictWeb = 1;
useContentFilter = 0;
useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
<Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
```

I think that the code is correct and I'm using the correct test IDs provided by Google. I'm running the code on a test device with iOS12 and i have updated Google Mobile Ads SDK to the latest version: 7.33.1.

Here is the code that I'm using:

AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application:UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {GADRequest().testDevices = [ "2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b" ]
    GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511")
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")   
    return true
}
func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
    let firstController = window?.rootViewController as! ViewController
    firstController.plusOneLife()
}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
}

func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd,
                        didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
    print("Reward based video ad failed to load.")
}
```

ViewController:

```
    @IBAction func watchAd(_ sender: Any) {
    if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady == true {
        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having the same issue as me, It is on Google's end.

I have reached out to them, you can monitor the progress at the link below here

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/ios/f-W_HmEndw4